# setInterval not working propely in chrome

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have some script in tampermonkey!!!! (it is important its chrome extention!) like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
         window.location = 'firstlink'; window.location = 'secondlink';}, 
    10000);
});
```

The problem is - it is only always sends the 'secondlink' (I can see it in the fiddler - HTTP requests)

So my question is: why was 'firstlink' never sents?

If it is not possible, then could you explain to me how to write correct script that sends 2 different links with some interval to the same site?

Comment: to understand you ,you want to navigate first to first link then take an interval then switch to the second link

Comment: no - i want navigate to the first link then to the second link, then wait some tine and after that repeat it all agian and again

Comment: I will write you the steps try to implement it then feed me back

Answer (score 0):

1- in index page you will make the following 
--> navigate to first page.
2- in first page 
--> navigate to second page.
3- in second page 
--> wait using set interval and then navigate to index page

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
    window.location = 'firstlink';
    window.location = 'secondlink';
    setInterval(function(){window.location = 'firstlink';}, 100*1000);
   });  not working too - constanlty goes to 'secindlink'

Comment: i don't understand your reply

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding you. i got what you meant - but not am not owner of the site - i am just payer of some web game and trying to write script to push 2 links with some perion of time